# how to name on duration rules

Tags: british-english, time, dates

I have a list of tasks, each happening between a start time and an end time. I want to sort all tasks into 3 categories:

1. Upcoming   ?
2. Current happening  ?
3. pass ? already end ?

What are the best words to name these categories?

Comment: Since [“event”](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/event) is such a good word to describe generically “something that takes place”, I’d use three words that are often used with “event” and go with: “**Event Status**: Upcoming…Current…Past.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. upcoming
2. in progress *or* active
3. done *or* complete

Comment: thanks for reply, if the task is like event or exhibition still can call `in progress or active,  done or complete` ? and how to name this sort way ? like `sort by time`?

Comment: You could also use "current" for state #2

Comment: The characteristic being described by each of these words could be called "progress" or "progress status" perhaps.

Comment: @MaxWilliams  so that would be like   `progress` : `upcoming`, `current`, `complete` ?

Comment: That's what I meant yes.  Ultimately in this context you just need the reader to be able to guess what you mean, ie for the names to be **intuitive** and I think these work from that perspective.

Comment: I would say *Sort by status* or *Sort by event status*.